# Bean 'getters' not returning a value

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans, jakarta-ee, javabeans

I'm doing a little project in Netbeans using Glassfish for a course I'm doing on Java EE. I'm having a problem where my 'getter' methods for the Bean are returning a null value and therefore nothing gets submitted to the database. The front-end to the project is a JSF page, which could be part of the problem. My suspicion it it's the bean, the JSF page or my configuration (of what? I don't know!) that is the problem

I'm very new to this topic so please forgive my lack of jargon and naivety on the subject!

Our course instructor has upload a project which is similar to what we need to create so we're all using that as a guide. His works perfectly whereas mine, which to me is identical, doesn't.

I can't post any extensive code, in order to comply with our institution's regulations but I can post a few snippets. If there's something specific that needs to be posted up, I'll do my best.

Bean:

```
@Named(value="secure")
@SessionScoped
public class Post implements Serializable {
private String post;
private String recipient;

@EJB private PostLocal posts; //local interface
public Post() {
}

public String getRecipient() {
    return recipient;
}

public void setRecipient(String recipient) {
    this.recipient= recipient;
}

public List<Post> getPosts() {
    return posts.getAllPosts();
}

public String getPost() {
    return post;
}

public void setPost(String post) {
    this.post = post;
}

public String submit() {
    Post p = new Post();
    byte[] encryptedMsg = p.encrypt(getPost(), "password"); //the post is encrypted, that's why it's stored as a byte array. getMessage returns null..
    p.setRecipient(getRecipient()); //getRecipient returns null
    p.setMessage(encryptedMsg);
    posts.add(s);
    return "index";

}
```

JSF page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
 <h:head>
    <title>Project</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
    <table>
        <tr>

            <td>
                Recipient:
            </td>
            <td>
                <h:inputText value="#{secure.recipient}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Enter a message to post here:
            </td>
            <td>
                <h:inputText value="#{secure.post}"></h:inputText>
            </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> <h:commandButton action="#{secure.submit}" value="Submit" /> </td>

        </tr>

    </table>

        <h:dataTable value="#{secure.posts}" var="thePosts">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
            #{thePosts.recipient}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Comment</f:facet>
            #{thePosts.post}
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
  </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Any questions, then please by all means ask! I'm completely stuck with this (and have been for the past 24 hours) so any help is greatly appreciated!

Many thanks

Comment: My thoughts are that the getRecipient and getPost methods maybe _are_ being called, but they just return the uninstantiated post/recipient variables declared a few lines above. So maybe that's the problem, but why it's happening, I do not know. In case anyone is wondering, the encrypt method is trying to call the getPost method to get the "post" (string of text from JSF form) and then takes the return value + a password (currently hardcoded as a String with the value "password" and then encrypts using DES/MD5 and returns the encrypted post in byte[] format

Comment: Think I've solved the problem myself. Been reading the JSF guru BalusC's blog and had the thought it could be a scoping issue. I then noticed my @SessionScoped import package was javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped ... I assumed this was the right one but upon changing it to javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped the issue was resolved! Getters are now returning values and the "p" object is persisted! Touch wood this isn't a coincidence and it'll keep on working as intended!

Comment: It was 3 years ago so I'm afraid I can't remember. A quick Google brings this up: http://balusc.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html - which might have been what I read at the time. I do remember clearly that I just imported the wrong package, so check you've got the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your resolution is correct. Reason- the bean you are using is a CDI bean and not JSF Managed bean. CDI beans are supported in JSF as a [JSR 299](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=299) support. The scope to be used in case of CDI bean is javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped. So what you have done is perfectly fine.